# Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server Nextjs14

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, hydration

I have coded a navbar in which there is searchicon, person icon and cart icon. I want to perform this action in nextjs14.

> The person Icon will be dynamic based on the auth state. If the user
> is authenticated it will show the avatar. otherwise it will show the
> person icon.

**After signup with credentials, I am getting this hydration error:**

[image]

**The file is marked with "use client" and My code snippet is:**

[image]

Thank you for your support

Comment: don't use `img` html tag instead of use nextjs provided `Image` tag

Comment: Image tags will be transpiled in img tag in browser. However, I tried but failed to solve the error